# How to apply an addClass to the parent of the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using :

```
$parent.addClass('error');
```

But I would like to add the invalid class to the "parent of the parent".
Is there a way to writte it, or is the only solution to specify the exact ID or class of this "greatparent" ?

Here is my html :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="">Label</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="1" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group error">
    <label class="control-label" for="">Label</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="2" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have many .control-group classes so I want to add the error class only on the focused one, so I can't do like this :

```
$(".control-group").addClass("error");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just use `$parent.parent().addClass...`

I would recommend checking out the jQuery docs, as it contains many useful functions like this. http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.parent()`, e.g.,:

```
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('error');
```

But you'll leave yourself some flexibility in your markup if you use `.closest()` instead:

```
$(this).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
```

Comment: Prior to "closest" the other way to do this was $(this).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');

Comment: It didn't actually worked for me, but the solution from @jani worked fine `$parent.parent().addClass('error');`

Comment: Would have helped if you had told us what $parent was :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
$("select-grandchild-here").parent().parent().addClass("error");

Comment: Thanks, that was the good idea, but no need for the grandchild : `$parent.parent().addClass('error');` worked fine